# how is echo -n $"some string" different then echo -n "some string"

Tags: string, sh

I am creating a startup script for my own service and looking at some of the existing service startup scripts for help.  In the /etc/init.d/atd startup script I see the following construct:

```
echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
```

I can't find any documentation on what starting a string with $ does.   It seems work exactly the same as not using a $ sign.  Any one know why you would do this and even better where this obscure use is documented?  Google is not helping so far.

The script is a /bin/sh (bourne shell) dialect.

This is on CentOS release 6.2 (Final)

Comment: Both are better done using the `printf` command, which is more powerful and much more consistent than the umpteen different implementations of `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign `$"string"` will cause the string to be translated according to the current locale. If the current locale is C or POSIX, the dollar sign is ignored. If the string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.